# Pivoting in Pandas - ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm pretty new to python and pandas and I'm trying to transform some data.
I have a dataset with three columns as shown below:

```
A       B               C
col1    21-03-2019      1.2
col2    21-03-2019      23
col3    21-03-2019      45
col4    21-03-2019      2.4
col5    21-03-2019      78
col1    14-07-2019      0.1
col2    14-07-2019      AM
col3    14-07-2019      CDM
col4    14-07-2019      66
col5    14-07-2019      0.1
```

I'm tyring to pivot the dataframe using B as my index and the pivot table works fine.

```
import pandas as pd 

# creating a dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3' ,'col4', 'col5'], 
      'B': [21-03-2019,21-03-2019,21-03-2019,21-03-2019,21-03-2019, 14-07-2019,14-07-2019,14-07-2019,14-07-2019,14-07-2019], 
      'C': [1.2, 23, 45, 2.4, 78, 0.1, 'AM', 'CDM', 66, 0.1]}) 

df.pivot(index='B', columns='A', values='C')



A            col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
B                           
21-03-2019  1.2   23   45   2.4   78
14-07-2019  0.1   AM   CDM  66    0.1
```

But there are situations in my dataframe where B column is same for all records, as shown below:

```
A       B               C
col1    21-03-2019      1.2
col2    21-03-2019      23
col3    21-03-2019      45
col4    21-03-2019      2.4
col5    21-03-2019      78
col1    21-03-2019      0.1
col2    21-03-2019      AM
col3    21-03-2019      CDM
col4    21-03-2019      66
col5    21-03-2019      0.1
```

In this case, the pivot fails with the below error:

`ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

I tried resetting the index (although I don't know what resetting index means) `df.pivot(index='B', columns='B', values='C').reset_index('B')` but it's still the same error.

My expected output is:

```
A           col1  col2 col3 col4  col5
B                           
21-03-2019  1.2   23   45   2.4   78
21-03-2019  0.1   AM   CDM  66    0.1
```

How can I solve this? Can someone please help me?

Comment: How do you want to aggregate `C` in those cases?

Comment: Hi @LearneR, welcome to Python/Pandas!  For learning more about things like resetting the index, you might find [this tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) useful.

Comment: @yatu: I don't really want any aggregation for C. I just want the values to be displayed  as-is.

Comment: One of the problems Pandas is having is that it doesn't know what logic to use to combine the rows, since `B` is the same for all rows.  What distinguishes the first `col1` from the second?  In the first dataframe it's the different values of `B`, but in the second dataframe Pandas isn't sure what to do.  Do you always want to pivot in groups of five?  Can you explain the underlying logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `col1` exist for each group and it is first is possible create helper column `g` by compare values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and cumulative sum [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['g'] = df['A'].eq('col1').cumsum()
```

And then for no aggregation solution use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['B', 'g', 'A'])['C'].unstack()
```

Or for aggregation by first value is possible use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['B', 'g'], columns='A', values='C', aggfunc='first')
print (df1)
A            col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
B          g                         
21-03-2019 1  1.2   23   45  2.4   78
           2  0.1   AM  CDM   66  0.1
```

Last is possible remove helper `level of MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df1)
A          col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
B                                  
21-03-2019  1.2   23   45  2.4   78
21-03-2019  0.1   AM  CDM   66  0.1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I used the one with `set_index()` and `unstack()` and it works perfectly for all my datasets. I really need to dig deeper into Pandas. I would've never come to this solution myself without your response. Thanks, again.